# R loop remove outliers

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, outliers

I am triying to build a loop to remove outliers:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df)){if (class(df[i,])=="numeric"){df[i,] <- df[df[i,] > quantile(df[i,],3/4)*3/2,]}}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in Ops.data.frame(df[i, ], quantile(df[i, ], 3/4) * 3/2) : 
  ‘>’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing rows and columns. Assuming `df` is a data.frame, `df[i, ]` will be a single-row data frame, which will be of class `data.frame`. Try operating over columns. Also make sure you *always* use `, i` in your brackets, you seem to be missing one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could speed this up by using lapply.

```
c1 = rnorm(10)
c2 = rnorm(10)
c3 = LETTERS[1:10]


df = cbind.data.frame(c1, c2, c3)

myfun = function(x, probs){
  if(class(x) == "numeric"){
    x[x > quantile(x, probs)] = NA
    return(x)
  }else{
    return(x)
  }

}
```

The example data.frame is

```
> df
            c1          c2 c3
1  -0.21304047  0.34942938  A
2   0.12141663 -1.41734891  B
3  -0.09297657  0.57998739  C
4  -0.70925140 -0.52620644  D
5   1.02440427  0.02377832  E
6   0.43631554  0.19125312  F
7   0.53268566  2.25430880  G
8  -0.37624920  0.14218233  H
9   0.03863661 -0.44441846  I
10  1.26889396 -0.12077335  J
```

Then, I'll record the quantiles before hand just to verify this is working

```
> quantile(df$c1, 3/4)
      75% 
0.5085931 

> quantile(df$c2, 3/4)
      75% 
0.3098853 

df = do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(df, myfun, 3/4))

> df


            c1          c2 c3
1  -0.21304047          NA  A
2   0.12141663 -1.41734891  B
3  -0.09297657          NA  C
4  -0.70925140 -0.52620644  D
5           NA  0.02377832  E
6   0.43631554  0.19125312  F
7           NA          NA  G
8  -0.37624920  0.14218233  H
9   0.03863661 -0.44441846  I
10          NA -0.12077335  J
```

So we do get the output that we expect.

To do this with a for loop we could run this

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)) if(class(df[, i]) == "numeric") df[, i][df[,i] > quantile(df[,i], 3/4)] = NA
```

This gives us the same result

```
> df
            c1          c2 c3
1  -0.21304047          NA  A
2   0.12141663 -1.41734891  B
3  -0.09297657          NA  C
4  -0.70925140 -0.52620644  D
5           NA  0.02377832  E
6   0.43631554  0.19125312  F
7           NA          NA  G
8  -0.37624920  0.14218233  H
9   0.03863661 -0.44441846  I
10          NA -0.12077335  J
```

Then, if we only want to keep rows without any NAs we could run this

```
df = df[complete.cases(df), ]
```