# user function to remove outliers

Tags: r, outliers

Using a 10 x 10 matrix to illustrate issue, see below.  [image: 10 x 0 matrix]

Am interested in looking at how to create a *user function* to remove outliers from certain data columns.  There are many good ways to address my query e.g. [Adapting a code for removing outliers- Function not running in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68371040/adapting-a-code-for-removing-outliers-function-not-running-in-loop). Would prefer however to understand how a user function could be employed.

My basic formula -

```r
Outliers <- boxplot (t$Yn)$out
```

Where n = x1, x4, x7

```r
t1_out <- t[-c(which(t$X1)%in%outliers)),]
t4_out <- t[-c(which(t$X4)%in%outliers)),]
t7_out <- t[-c(which(t$X7)%in%outliers)),]
```

My question - how can I create a user function to carry out the manipulations for t$X1, t$X4, t$X7, using the following approach?

```
function_name <- function (arg1, arg2, ...){
  statements  # do useful stuff 
  object      # return something
}
```

The challenge for me is in understanding how to work with two operations within the user formula.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include your sample matrix as *text* (i.e. cut and paste into a code block) rather than as an image? If you're unsure how to edit, you can dump the text and someone will help you format it correctly ...

Comment: And, can you clarify what you mean by a "user function" ?

Comment: Thx Ben for edit advice, am still learning.  'User Function' - a function defined by the user, to carry out an operation not built into r (such as sum(), mean() etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
example <- data.frame(X1 = sample(c(1, 2, 5, 40:60, 98, 99), 50, TRUE),
                      X2 = sample(c(1, 2, 3, 40:60, 92, 99), 50, TRUE),
                      X3 = sample(c(1, 2, 7, 40:60, 97, 98), 50, TRUE))
head(example, 10)
boxplot(example)

clean <- function(v){
  bp <- boxplot.stats(v)
  v[-which(v %in% bp$out)]
}

boxplot(example$X1, clean(example$X1),
        example$X2, clean(example$X2),
        example$X3, clean(example$X3),
        col = c("blue", "red"))
legend("topright", fill = c("blue", "red"), legend = c("before clean", "after clean"))
```

The function `clean` accepts a vector of numerics and returns it without the outliers (as defined by boxplot.stats) just the way you did.

```
vector <- rbeta(50, 10, 1)
plot(density(vector))
lines(density(clean(vector)), col = "red")
```